Query execution time degradation after simple update in postgresql
Postresql. Managed database with cloud provider.
During release I've run sql migration by Entity framework with simple sql script. And exactly after that tables where update was applied with became very slow for query (and it seems not ony that tables).
To undestand how slow.. query took 1-2 sec before and now it takes 2-5 minutes.
Sql script looks like update requests set state = 3 where state = 1;.
Table holds 1.5 million records. And script affected about 95% rows of table.
Table looks like uuid id, timestamp created_at, int state, int ownerId and few other columns.
Table has index only for pk id and foreign key ownerId
What reason can be for such degradation?
f.ex. 500 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 6 m 1 s 19 ms (execution: 6 m 0 s 606 ms, fetching: 413 ms)
I've added monitoring screen. You can see moment of update during release process about 12.12.2024 00:00. But then monitoring looks normal but problem remain. Also notice please that free disk space was increased manually by me in an attempt to alleviate the issue..



I discuss this problem with support but it goes not very productive. So try to find desicion with community

If you changed 95% of the rows, presumably the query now returns different results. It would not be surprising if it takes different amounts of time, for example if the query used to return 1% of the table but now returns 94% of it.  You need to show the query and the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

Do you have access to the system metrics? CPU, I/O, pg_stat_database, pg_stat_activity, that kind of stuff? If you do, post what you see, in addition to

jjanes, usual query is 'select * from requests order by created_at desc limit 500'. So result set 500 is not changed but duration grew cardinally

@mustaccio, I've added monitoring screens

Try VACUUM (FULL) requests, followed by VACUUM (ANALYZE) requests and see if that changes anything.

@Laurenz Albe, I'll try tonight. So I get one idea. Previously, all records were physically stored in the heap file in the order they were created (that is, the created_at column). And the query with sorting by this column was quickly performed even through a simple seq scan. And after the update, the rows were scattered throughout the file. And now sorting by this column must scan the entire table. May be?

No, it's about getting rid of bloat.

Finally vacuum (full) solved problem. DB file size returned to initial size and queries executes normally.
